# When i try to compile typescript code into javascript, getting **Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not an array type or a string type**

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

When i try to compile typescript code into javascript, getting **Type 'NodeListOf' is not an array type or a string type**.

```
if (query.length) {                                              
  var regex = new RegExp("(" + query + ")", "gm"); 
  var li = document.querySelectorAll("#id li"); //error                 
    for (var Element of li){                                   
      Element.innerHTML = Element.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="classname">$1</span>'); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error is on the `forEach` line, not the `querySelector` line. The problem is what it is saying it is, which is that a NodeList is not an array type. Try `[...li]` or `Array.from(li)`. Also, why are you looping twice, once with `forEach` and then again with `for...of`?

Comment: @torazaburo after removing for each loop still getting same error.

Comment: As I said, you have to do `for (var Element of Array.from(li))`. Or, if you don't have `Array.from` available, then `for (var x = 0; x < li.length; x++) li[x].innerHTML...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below compiles fine and I've added comments inline.

```
let query = '';
if (query.length) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("(" + query + ")", "gim");
    var li: NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelectorAll("#test li");
    // ES5 does not allow TS iteration of NodeListOf<Element> nor use of Array.from 
    // so it is necessary to loop over it manually.
    // Note that Element is an existing type which caused a conflict with "(var Element of list)".
    // It was necessary to rename Element to element.
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        let element = li[i];
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(pattern, '<span class="target">$1</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird! Turns out that an absent `tsconfig.json` file will cause `tsc` to assume that `Array.from` is available, even though it's an ES2015 capability. I've corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This does also work:

```
let elements: any = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
for(let ele of elements) {
     // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..  will solve the problems.

```js
if (query.length) {                                              
  var pattern = new RegExp("(" + query + ")", "gim"); 
  var li = document.querySelectorAll("#test li");                 
   for (var Element of <any> li){                                   
      Element.innerHTML = Element.innerHTML.replace(pattern, '<span class="target">$1</span>'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Casting `li` to `any` will suppress the error message, but I'm not sure that it resolves the underlying incompatibility.